# Touch Screen monitor double clicking

Tags: touchscreen

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS, This is in combination with a Hanns.G HT161HNB touch screen monitor.

When clicking on the icon in the bottom left for Applications it immediately opens the window then closes straight away.

`libinput debug-events` shows the following output from a single touch:

```
TOUCH_DOWN
TOUCH_FRAME
TOUCH_UP
TOUCH_FRAME
```

I'm not too sure on how to go about resolving this, it's almost as if it is registered as a double click.

I have tried to google and browse other answers however I don't seem to be getting anywhere, Could anyone please point me in the correct direction for some more reading to try and resolve this issue.

My Linux knowledge is a little weak so please excuse me if my question appears to be trivial/stupid. :)

Just used the following:

`xinput --test DEVICE_NAME_HERE`

Whilst xinput is running in test mode the button works as it should! The second I close the xinput test the behaviour goes back to the same (Opens then closes the application menu).
Can anyone advise why it works when xinput is running in test mode?

Many thanks,
Phil

Comment: Your `libinput debug-events` output is normal. It's unclear what's happening. Might be useful the output of `xinput`.

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue with an Asus Zenbook on Ubuntu 22.04. Did you find a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

it's doing the same on mine machine, the way I got round this was by using two fingers, which acts as a right click, give it a try.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Sadly it still behaves in the same way.
I've found that pressing the icon then swiping my finger to the right works too.